# Some exceptions in retrieving data from my database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP5eU.png)
this is my exeption:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The expression 'listCombo.CurriculumId' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

And I tried to follow microsoft but it still doesn't work

I tried Include curriculumId but it didn't work

Comment: Please show us your code (as text, not a screenshot) - in particular the declaration of your `Combo` class.